# Django/South: What is the proper way to set related_name arguments for the intermediate model on a ManyToMany to self relation?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

This is related to a [question I asked yesterday about migrating a change from a ForeignKey to self to a ManyToManyField to self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553054/how-do-i-generate-a-migration-for-changing-a-foreignkey-to-self-to-a-manytoman), however because I'm only prototyping an app for the time being/due to time constraints, I've decided to just drop the relevant tables and reset the migration history.

These are the relevant models/fields:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    nominator = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False,                
            verbose_name=_('nominator'), through='Nomination', null=True,        
            blank=True)


class Nomination(models.Model):                                                  
    nominee = models.ForeignKey(Person)                                          
    nominator = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

However, this doesn't even generate an initial migration:

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration nominations --initial
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
nominations.nomination: Accessor for field 'nominee' clashes with related field 'Person.nomination_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'nominee'.
nominations.nomination: Accessor for field 'nominator' clashes with related field 'Person.nomination_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'nominator'.
```

I followed the instructions to add a `related_name` argument to the `nominator` and `nominee` fields on the `Nomination` model, like so:

```
class Nomination(models.Model):                                                  
    nominee = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name=_('nominator'))             
    nominator = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name=_('nominee'))
```

That gave me a different error:

```
$ ./manage.py schemamigration nominations --initial
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
nominations.nomination: Accessor for field 'nominee' clashes with m2m field 'Person.nominator'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'nominee'.
nominations.nomination: Reverse query name for field 'nominee' clashes with m2m field 'Person.nominator'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'nominee'.
```

I'm not sure what to do from this point. I get the feeling that I've forgotten something the `Person` model, but I'm not sure what that could be since both the Django/South docs are not terribly forthcoming when it comes to this kind of relation.

Comment: Just use different names other than the fields names. Something like `person_nominator` and `person_nominee`

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought for sure it had something to do with the field on the `Person` model itself. It does make sense now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Just use different names other than the fields names. Something like person_nominator and person_nominee.

I move this comment to an answer so that the question is no longer without an answer.