# How to set related_name with a ManyToManyField using a through table and pointing to self

Tags: django, django-models

I have a task class, that can have sub-tasks, so it's a cyclic relationship. I'm passing it through a linker model/table like so:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name="tasks")
    dependancy = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Dependancy', null=True, 
        blank=True, through_fields=('task', 'sub_task'), symmetrical=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Dependancy(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    sub_task = models.ForeignKey(Task)
```

But I get this error:

```
ERRORS:
gantt_charts.dependency.sub_task: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'dependency.sub_task' clashes with field name 'Task.dependency'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Task.dependency', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'dependency.sub_task'.
gantt_charts.dependency.sub_task: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'dependency.sub_task' clashes with reverse accessor for 'dependency.task'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'dependency.sub_task' or 'dependency.task'.


gantt_charts.dependency.task: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'dependency.task' clashes with field name 'Task.dependency'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Task.dependency', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'dependency.task'.
gantt_charts.dependency.task: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'dependency.task' clashes with reverse accessor for 'dependency.sub_task'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'dependency.task' or 'dependency.sub_task'.
```

Obviously I need to set the related name on the Dependency.sub_task and Dependency.task field, and following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19568239/1075247) is to name them something like `task_task` and `task_sub_task`, but that sounds wrong, unintuitive and confusing.

What would be a clear and concise name for them? It'd be easier if I wasn't getting confused over what related_names were, when using a linking table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given a `Task` instance, how can you access all the `Dependencies` that have that as their `task`? Or their `sub_task`? That's the purpose of `related_name`—it provides the name for the attribute that Django will create on `Task` to point to that group of things.

You're seeing that error because Django automatically uses the name `<model>_set`, and since you have two `ForeignKeys` pointing to the same model, the default name will conflict.

Now, it might be that you never need to directly access `Dependencies` that way. If that's the case you can add `related_name='+'` to both fields and the reverse attribute won't be created at all (and your errors will disappear).

If you do want to access them, the name is up to you. I prefer longer-but-more-descriptive names to make their purpose clear. I might model the problem like this:

```
class Task(models.Model): 
    subtasks = models.ManyToManyField('self', 
                                      through='Dependancy',
                                      symmetrical=False,
                                      through_fields=('supertask', 'subtask'),
                                      related_name='supertasks')

class Dependancy(models.Model):
    supertask = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='dependencies_as_supertask')
    subtask = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='dependencies_as_subtask')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('supertask', 'subtask')


>>> task = Task.objects.get()

>>> # all the Tasks that are supertasks of this one
>>> task.supertasks

>>> # all the Tasks that are subtasks of this one
>>> task.subtasks

>>> # all the Dependencies with this Task as the supertask
>>> task.dependencies_as_supertask

>>> # all the Dependencies with this Task as the subtask
>>> task.dependencies_as_subtask
```

Comment: **Given a Task instance, how can you access all the Dependencies that have that as their task?** Brilliant, crystal clear explanation. Thanks

Comment: Am I right in thinking that `self.dependency_sub_task.task` gets '*all the tasks that have 'task' as their subtask*'? and `self.dependency_task.sub_tasks` gets '*all the tasks that have 'task' as their task*'. Where 'task' is given by 'self'.

Comment: No, remember that using the related_name will access a queryset of objects, not a single object. So `dependency_sub_task` is a bad name, make it plural. I've edited the question with my recommended approach, and showed how you would access all the related tasks.